# Info on 1980's Black and Decker contractor saw with rack & pinion fence?

Tags: table-saw

I was wondering if anyone has ever owned/ heard of a Black and Decker Contractor Table Saw with a rack and pinion fence, released sometimes in the 80's. My dad told me about these saws but I would like more information, as Google comes up with nothing. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to WW.SE! What information are you looking for? That's what your question should be asking for, as that's really what you're after (and what others may be after as well).

Comment: For example, a B&D company, DeWalt, makes table saws with R&P fences...

Comment: True. But this one was made in the 80s and Says Black and Decker

Comment: Well, it's unclear exactly what you want to know, but there is this: http://vintagemachinery.org/pubs/detail.aspx?id=1658 (This link is sure to be dead in an internet moment, so use it or lose it.)

Comment: @jdv thanks, but coincidently I have that saw. Close but much bigger and belt driven.